# json.net needs to convert my class property to

Tags: .net, json

I have the following two classes.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Args { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Args = new Bar();
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When using:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Args.Name = "Mikael";
foo.Args.Age = 12;
string o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
Console.WriteLine(o);
```

I get the following json:

```
{"Args":{"Name":"Mikael","Age":12}}
```

This is somewhat correct i guess ... but the other end I'm sending it to expects the Args to be an array, so it needs to look like this:

```
{"Args":[{"Name":"Mikael","Age":12}]}
```

Otherwise it sees the Args as a single object and not an array.

Can this be done with [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FooWrapper
{
    private Foo myfoo;

    public Bar[] Args { get { 
      Bar[] bar=new Bar[1]();
      bar[0]=myfoo.Bar;
      return bar;
    }}

    public FooWrapper(Foo foo)
    {
        myfoo=foo;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.Args.Name = "Mikael";
foo.Args.Age = 12;
string o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new FooWrapper(foo));
Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Comment: What a hacky yet simple solution. I Love it. Havent thought about it. Still would leave the question open if there are a more elegant solution with a Attribute or SerializerSettings.

Comment: @Syska Not wanting to defend this answer, but there is a bit more to it: A solution with Attributes etc. might or might not be portable to another sort of serializer. So if you want to keep the liberty to freely chose your serializer, you need to structure your object the way the consumer wants it. You can do this by changing it (@scottm's answer) or by wrapping it (my answer)

Comment: I'm awere of that. Thats why I also wrote the "Attribute or SerializerSettings". With Attribute I will be dependent on Json.NET but with the other I will have freedom and other could serialize how they want. The consumer wants the Args as an array. But in this context I see no reason why the consuming product want this as an array. But ... this seems like a solid solution. First I thought there json deserializer had a bug, but it was my code :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `Args` property to an array of `Bar`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar[] Args { get; set; }
}

    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Args = new Bar[] { new Bar {Name = "Mikael", Age = 12}};

    string o = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Comment: Think the most correct answer goes to Eugen Rieck so this will keep my model clean. But still the very same simple answer.